# How can I link a gallery made with views to another gallery made in views?

Tags: views, media, navigation, uri

I am trying to do a gallery with a page of preview of the pics, I got how to do it with views and tags for the full size pictures and with image styles; I got the preview gallery (btw for this one I am using Nodequeues). 
Now I don't know how to link the galleries from the previews to the full size ones, I did try with the output linking in the override section of the view, I tried creating a new field with the URL and nothing, it always links to content/node but not to /photos/node[image: Views]

Btw this is the website http://www.nellens.com/home/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for using a view into another as a field then you can use [Views Field View](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to achieve this.

Module page describe :

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying all the morning to solve this using the module but I think it could solve another case and not this, I am very new into this, maybe I am wrong, please if you can help me that would be great, thanks for the answer!